# SharePoint custom page post form with windows authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-authentication

I am new to SharePoint and want to understand how to get the logged in (windows authentication) user details when I submit a custom form to a co-hosted WCF endpoint?

```
**HTML**    
<form action="/TestWCF/Submit" method="post">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

**WCF**
    public void Submit(User user)
    {

    }
```

Does the rendered SharePoint page stores a cookie which I should pass along with my custom post method? because if its a asp.net web app I can get a token stored in client and send to server and validate it. but SharePoint I don't have much control.

Answer (score 0):

The username is custom validated. This is done by the FarmService.Authentication.DistributorValidator class in the FarmService assembly. This class inherits from WCF class UserNamePasswordValidator and overrides the Validate method.

```
public class DistributorValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
```

{

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)

{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))

        throw new SecurityTokenException("Username and password required");

    var repository = new DistributorRepository();

    if (! repository.IsKnownDistributor(userName, password))

        throw new FaultException(string.Format("Wrong username ({0}) or password ", userName));

}
```

}

Except for one detail which is absolutely essential. For username password authentication to work your server hosting the service needs an X509 certificate. Else all service invocations will fail. This certificate is specified in the service behavior.

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="Farm" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople"  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
```

First you need a certificate. Instead of buying one (which is bound to a specific server address and thereby as good as useless for testing purposes) you can create your own. The .net framework comes with tools to generate these and there are several tutorials how to use these tools. Far more easier is selfcert a pluralsight tool which takes care of the whole process in a couple of clicks.

What they don’t tell you here is that you have to run the tool as administrator, else it will crash most ungracefully. What the tool is also unclear about is where to store the generated certificate. By default it is stored in MyStore. When validating the certificate it’s trustworthiness depends on the location it is stored. When the store is not trusted a chain of validation is started. Instead of setting up a chain of certificates you can also directly store your certificate in a trusted store.

To consume this service add a service reference in the client. The mexHttpBinding in the service configuration enables to read all metadata form the service without any credentials.

Setting up a connection to the client requires some fiddling. Again not all of these settings are clear by default.

```
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(Farm.FarmUrl), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("Farm"));

var binding = new WSHttpBinding();

binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;

binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
var result = new CustomerDeskOperationsClient(binding, endPoint);

result.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Farm.FarmUserName;

result.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Farm.FarmPassword;
```

Details can refer to [A simple WCF service with username password authentication](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the response but my question is more towards a html form post to WCF Endpoint.